# apt-get not working on xampp

Tags: apache, xampp, windows-10, apt-get

I have a Windows 10 64-bit PC that runs a XAMPP instance, with a simple website and local MySQL server.

I need to install a few things on this Apache server via command line, so I'm going to the "shell" option from the Xampp control panel. But when I run the "apt-get" command, it says that there is no such thing.

Why don't I have it and how do I get it on this local server?

Comment: apt-get is a linux command. it is not available on windows 10

Comment: I know. I'm trying to run it from the internal command line ("shell") of the Xampp's apache server...

Comment: If you are using it on Windows it will never work. "apt-get" or "Apt" only exists on an Ubuntu/Debian server. Xampp apache server has nothing related to run that.

Comment: So I can't install anything on this Xampp server I have??

Comment: Although Xampp is indeed installed on my Windows 10 PC, it is running an Apache web server, so this command line ("shell") should be running commands under a Linux environment. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I have this question too, if there is answer please share with us